# Вывод дополнительного поля в подразделе Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, интернет-магазин

День добрый! Подскажите как вывести метку (либо произвольное поле) в подразделе с низу, чтобы конкретно эта метка (либо произвольное поле) выводилось под категорией.

Примерно я хочу вот так:
http://prntscr.com/fdbool это получается подраздел

Подскажите как это можно реализовать… чтобы эта надпись (MDX 2014) была еще кликабельна к карточкам, в которых проставлены эти метки.

Принцип работы такой:
в карточке товара прописана мтка MDX 2014, и вот это слово MDX 2014 должно выводится снизу подраздела..

Уже 4 день ломаю голову, не знаю как реализовать..

Answer (score 0):

Используйте нижеприведенный хук в functions.php:

```
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item(  ) { 
  //  здесь вставьте нужный html
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Не получилось( Есть еще варианты может? http://prntscr.com/fez3ho Вот тут из 3 нужно вывести метку, которая в 3 разделе находится в самой карточке товара http://prntscr.com/fez3u4

Comment: Вы сайт ваш покажите и страницу на нем проблемную. Вывод разный, я показал код для страницы каталога.

Answer (score 0):

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
```

Comment: так вы вивыведете все названия меток поста